# Redirect both cout and stdout to a string in C++ for Unit Testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, stdout, legacy-code

I'm working on getting some legacy code under unit tests and sometimes the only way to sense an existing program behavior is from the console output.

I see lots of examples online for how to redirect stdout to another file in C++, but is there a way I can redirect it to an in-memory stream so my tests don't have to rely on the disk?

I'd like to get anything that the legacy code sends to stdout into a std::string so I can easily .find on the output.

**Edit**

The legacy code is so bad that it users a mixture of `cout << ..` and `printf`. Here is what I have so far:

```
void TestSuite::setUp(void)
{
    oldStdoutBuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::cout.rdbuf(consoleOutput.rdbuf());
}
void TestSuite::tearDown(void)
{
    std::cout.rdbuf(oldStdoutBuf);
}
```

The problem is that this does **not** capture output using printf. I would like something that gets both. Any ideas?

Comment: None of the answers below have worked for me, do you have a working example for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) may be what you're looking for.

**UPDATE**
Alright, this is a bit of hack, but maybe you could do this to grab the printf output:

```
char huge_string_buf[MASSIVE_SIZE];
freopen("NUL", "a", stdout);
setbuf(stdout, huge_string_buffer);
```

Note you should use "/dev/null" for linux instead of "NUL".  That will rapidly start to fill up huge_string_buffer.  If you want to be able to continue redirecting output after the buffer is full you'll have to call fflush(), otherwise it will throw an error.  See [`std::setbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setbuf) for more info.

Comment: Accepted your answer as stringstream was good pointer and your UPDATE is about as far as we will probably get without writing some hugely massive convoluted mess, for now I think I'll just write to a file and hopefully I won't need the printf output for many tests.

Comment: Works well, but if i use multiple unit tests, some fail with an exception because the buffer is already freed and stdout is written into it. In case of only a temporarly redirection into the buffer use a `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` at the end of the usage.

Comment: See this answer to avoid the "NUL"-Hack on POSIX systems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19499003/1557062

Comment: Don't understand how one should use stringstream for this tho... Sorry for being a noobie

Answer (score 3):

You can use `freopen(..., stdout)` and then dump the file into memory or a `std::string`.

Comment: I would really like to skip having to use the filesystem. Something that only uses ram would be best.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an alternative:

```
char bigOutBuf[8192];
char savBuf[8192];

fflush(stdout);
setvbuf(stdout,bigOutBuf,IOFBF,8192);//stdout uses your buffer

//after each operation
strncpy(savBuf,bigOutBuf,8192);//won't flush until full or fflush called

//...

//at long last finished
setbuf(stdout,NULL);//reset to unnamed buffer
```

This just intercepts the buffered output, so still goes to console or wherever.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to suppress the console output entirely, keeping just the captured buffer is it possible?

Answer (score -4):

Try sprintf, that's more efficient.

```
int i;
char str[] = "asdf";
char output[256];
sprintf(output, "asdfasdf %s %d\n", str, i);
```