# redirect output of an function printing to console to string

Tags: c++, c++11

lets say we have a function which prints text to the console and in which we do not have control over the source but we are able to call it. For example

```
void foo() {
    std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl; 
    print_to_console(); // this could be printed from anything
}
```

is it possible to redirect the output of the above function to a string without changing the function itself?

I'm not looking for a way to do this via terminal

Comment: Are you asking to redirect the `std::cout` temporarily. Or the output of the function `print_to_console()` temporarily for just  this call or the function `foo()`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes. That can be done. Here is a little demo:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void print_to_console() {
    std::cout << "Hello from print_to_console()" << std::endl;
}

void foo(){
  std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl; 
  print_to_console(); // this could be printed from anything
}
int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    //change the underlying buffer and save the old buffer
    auto old_buf = std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf()); 

    foo(); //all the std::cout goes to ss

    std::cout.rdbuf(old_buf); //reset

    std::cout << "<redirected-output>\n" 
              << ss.str() 
              << "</redirected-output>" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
<redirected-output>
hello world
Hello from print_to_console()
</redirected-output>
```

See [Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2941c7b9ced12065).

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot you could do this.

Comment: `auto *old_buf`? Is the pointer needed? auto doesn't discard pointer.

Comment: @Praetorian: No. The `*` is not needed. I wrote that out of habit :P

Comment: *But I thought you weren't supposed to use auto ptr* :p

Comment: What happens if they used printf, puts, write, etc ?

Comment: @AndreKostur: See my *other* solution (posted as another answer). :-)

Answer (score 7):

@Andre asked in the comment of my first answer:

> What happens if they used printf, puts, write, etc ? – Andre Kostur

For `printf`, I came up with the following solution. It will work only on POSIX as [fmemopen](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/978b731bb709f9fa) is available on POSIX only, but you can use *temporary* file instead if you want to — that will be better if you want a *portable* solution. The basic idea will be same.

```
#include <cstdio>

void print_to_console() {
    std::printf( "Hello from print_to_console()\n" );
}

void foo(){
  std::printf("hello world\n");
  print_to_console(); // this could be printed from anything
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    auto fp = fmemopen(buffer, 1024, "w");
    if ( !fp ) { std::printf("error"); return 0; }

    auto old = stdout;
    stdout = fp;

    foo(); //all the std::printf goes to buffer (using fp);

    std::fclose(fp);
    stdout = old; //reset

    std::printf("<redirected-output>\n%s</redirected-output>", buffer);
}
```

Output:

```
<redirected-output>
hello world
Hello from print_to_console()
</redirected-output>
```

[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/978b731bb709f9fa).

Comment: Not to throw wrenches into it... but will this necessarily work for both streams and stdout?   Perhaps re-opening file descriptor 1 may work for both cases.  (Still assuming POSIX)

Answer (score 1):

```
class buffer
    : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    buffer(std::ostream& os)
        : stream(os), buf(os.rdbuf())
    { }

    ~buffer()
     {
         stream.rdbuf(buf);
     }

private:
    std::ostream& stream;
    std::streambuf* buf;
};

int main()
{
    buffer buf(std::cout);
    std::stringbuf sbuf;

    std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf);

    std::cout << "Hello, World\n";
}
```

Comment: If you want to make it RAII, why not do [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71d90cb0a3459b65) which makes the client code cleaner. :-)