# Force print to terminal (std::cout is being piped)

Tags: c++, io, std, cout

**Context:**

I'm editing a small piece of a large program. This large program is controlling std::cout and rerouting it so that a basic piece of code like:

```
std::cout << "I want to see the light of the terminal!" << std::endl;
```

Does not display anything to the user.

**Question:**

How can I get something to print *directly* to the terminal when my standard output/error is being rerouted? (If possible)

**Other notes:**

I realize that I could edit the larger program, but I'm looking to use this printout for some early diagnostics before more fully integrating my code into the program. Having to mess with how the program routes the output would really extend the development cycle.

I am also currently writing to a file as a workaround but that's slightly less desirable and frankly I would like to know how to do this in the future.

Comment: Solutions will be system dependent, but you can try writing to `/dev/tty`

Comment: Have you tried outputting to `std::cerr`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes, I've noted that I've tried standard error. It's a good suggestion for others though.

Comment: I think that the large program should be modified to only redirect `stdout` but not `stderr` so that the little program could use `stderr` to write on the screen.

Comment: @Phil1970 that's it's not my call to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it following these steps:

1. Save the redirected buffer
2. Change buffer to console
3. Get your job done
4. Again set buffer to the saved buffer in step 1

For example

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void print_to_console() {
    std::cout << "Hello from print_to_console()" << std::endl;
}

void foo(){
  std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl; 
  print_to_console(); // this could be printed from anything
}
int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    //change the underlying buffer and save the old buffer
    auto old_buf = std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf()); 

    foo(); //all the std::cout goes to ss

    std::cout.rdbuf(old_buf); //reset

    std::cout << "<redirected-output>\n" 
              << ss.str() 
              << "</redirected-output>" << std::endl;
}
```

I haven't tested it. I took the idea and example from [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485536/redirect-output-of-an-function-printing-to-console-to-string).

**For convenience**, you can just write a function to print in console. This function will take care of the redirection and printing.

Answer (score 0):

Write to `stdout` and read from `stdin` (both are `FILE` descriptors).
You can wrap them in stream classes if you wish.. IE: Using `streambuf` and `iostream`to get the same functionality as `cout`.

```
#include <iostream>



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const char* data = "DATA TO PRINT";
    fwrite(data, strlen(data), sizeof(char), stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Small example:

```
#include <iostream>

class stream : public std::streambuf
{
private:
    int_type overflow(int_type c  = traits_type::eof());

public:
    stream() {}
    virtual ~stream() {}

    stream(const stream& other) = delete;
    stream& operator = (const stream& other) = delete;
};

stream::int_type stream::overflow(stream::int_type c)
{
    if (c != traits_type::eof())
    {
        fwrite(&c, 1, sizeof(c), stdout);
    }

    return c;
}

class mcout : public std::ostream
{
public:
    mcout() : std::ostream(0), sbuf() {init(&sbuf);}
    virtual ~mcout() {}

private:
    stream sbuf;
} mcout;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    mcout << "HELLO\n";

    return 0;
}
```