# Redirecting CUDA printf to a C++ stream

Tags: c++, linux, logging, cuda, io-redirection

### Problem statement

I am working on a large project which uses a logger for debugging. Since I like to keep a trace of what's happening in some CUDA kernels, I tried to find a way to redirect the [`printf`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output) of my CUDA kernels to a `stringstream` (or any stream), which can then be forwarded to the logger.

### Possible solution

I managed to do it by using the following code:

```cpp
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // dup

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> // stringstream
#include <fstream> // ofstream

char* output_file = "printf_redirect.log";

__global__ void printf_redirect(int* src, int* res)
{
    res[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
    printf("  %i: Hello World!\n", res[threadIdx.x]);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const uint N = 2;

    // Note: dummy arrays are not actually used, but this should prevent the
    //       compiler from discarding the printf in the kernel.

    int *d_A, *d_B, *h_A, *h_B;
    size_t size = N * sizeof (int);
    cudaMalloc (&d_A, size);
    cudaMalloc (&d_B, size);
    h_A = (int*) malloc (size);
    h_B = (int*) malloc (size);
    cudaMemcpy (d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    std::cout << "std::cout - start" << std::endl;
    printf ("stdout - start\n");

    /// REGULAR PRINT
    // Print to regular stdout
    std::cout << "Output to stdout:" << std::endl;
    printf_redirect<<<1,1>>> (d_A, d_B);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize ();

    /// REDIRECTION TO STRINGSTREAM
    std::stringstream ss;
    // Redirect std::cout to a stringstream
    std::streambuf* backup_cout = std::cout.rdbuf ();
    std::cout.rdbuf (ss.rdbuf ());
    // Redirect stdout to a buffer
    char buf[1024] = "";
    int backup_stdout = dup (fileno (stdout));
    freopen ("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
    setbuf (stdout, buf);

    std::cout << "Redirected output:" << std::endl;
    printf_redirect<<<1,N>>> (d_A, d_B);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize ();

    // Add CUDA buffer to a stringstream
    ss << buf;

    // Write stringstream to file
    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open (output_file);
    outFile << ss.str ();
    outFile.close ();

    /// RESET REDIRECTION
    // Redirect back to initial stdout
    fflush (stdout);
    setbuf (stdout, NULL);
    fclose (stdout);
    FILE *fp = fdopen (backup_stdout, "w");
    fclose (stdout);
    *stdout = *fp;
    // Redirect back to initial std::cout
    std::cout.rdbuf (backup_cout);

    std::cout << "std::cout - end" << std::endl;
    printf ("stdout - end\n");

    cudaMemcpy(h_B, d_B, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    free (h_A);
    free (h_B);
}
```

I used the following questions to achieve this:

- [Redirect both cout and stdout to a string in C++ for Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162068/redirect-both-cout-and-stdout-to-a-string-in-c-for-unit-testing)
- [How to redirect the output back to the screen after freopen(“out.txt”, “a”, stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdo)

Running the program, we get in the console:

```
std::cout - start
stdout - start
Output to stdout:
  0: Hello World!
std::cout - end
stdout - end
```

And in `printf_redirect.log`:

```
Redirected output:
  0: Hello World!
  1: Hello World!
```

### Question

Is there any easier way to achieve this? (e.g. hidden CUDA option or neat C/C++ trick)

Note that the final solution will end up in a utility class to make this less verbose in the actual code.

Comment: I see that when trying to do cout from the kernel the compiler gives an error telling that it can't be done as this is a host function. Could you explain why cout is considered as a host function and not printf?

Answer (score 7):

Device side `printf()` causes implicit serialization of the threads that are printing so you probably wouldn't want to use it in production code.

Device side `printf()` works by having the kernel copy messages to a preallocated ring buffer. Upon implicit or explit device synchronization (cudaDeviceSynchronize()), CUDA dumps any contents in the buffer to `stdout` and then clears it.

You could simply implement your own device `printf()`. Its performance would probably not be any worse than the built in one. The only disadvantage is that you would have to pass the ring buffer to the kernel and add a call to process it after the kernel returns.

Implementation would be something like this:

- Create a buffer with room for a fixed numer of `printf()` formatting strings and associated 32-bit or 64-bit parameters.
- Create a device function that uses `atomicInc()` to keep track of the current print location and takes a formatting string and parameters and copies them into the current location.
- Pass the ring buffer to the kernel, which then passes it to the device function together with the print parameters.
- Create a host function that takes the ring buffer, runs the formatting strings and parameters through host side `sprintf()` and passes the results to the logger.

Comment: There is an older `cuprintf` which was released as source by NVIDIA to developers pre Fermi. I am sure it could be adapted for the purpose.

Comment: The older `cuPrintf` is still "available" in the cuda simplePrintf [sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpleprintf).

Comment: I see that when trying to do cout<< from the kernel the compiler gives an error telling that it can't be done as this is a host function. Could you explain why cout is considered as a host function and not printf()?